Delphi - Check windows printer preference (allow windows to manage the default printer)
I follow this post
Change default printer on Windows 11 [delphi] [windows-11] [printing]
and it gives a solution when Printer preferences ‘Let Windows manage my default printer‘ is off.
There's a way, in Delphi 11 or 12, to get and change the Printer preferences ‘Let Windows manage my default printer‘ to off when it's on ??
Thanks to all for any help.

Just access the Registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows and set LegacyDefaultPrinterMode to 0 - not every setting has a dedicated WinAPI function.
